# Create n number of sequential chunks of a JSON array

Tags: javascript

How can I create specific chunks out of the below JSON array in sequence.

E.g. if I want 3 chunks the output should pick each first element of subset so Output will be

Desired output  ->

```
 [ {
            name: "Theme 1"
          },
        {
            name: "Theme 4"
          },
        {
            name: "Theme 7"
          },
        {
            name: "Theme 10"
          }
        ],

        [
        {
            name: "Theme 2"
          },
        {
            name: "Theme 5"
          },
        {
            name: "Theme 8"
          }
        ],

        [
        {  name: "Theme 3"},{  name: "Theme 6"},{  name: "Theme 9"}
        ]
```

This is what i have tried for 2 chunks cannot make it n number of chunks

```js
  const input = [{
    name: "Theme 1"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 2"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 3"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 4"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 5"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 6"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 7"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 8"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 9"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 10"
  }
];
  
  const chunkify = (inputArray) => {

    const chunks = 2;

    const chunk1 = [];
    const chunk2 = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {

      // Split array into 2 chunks 1st element goes in chunk 1 2nd element goes in chunk 2 , 3rd element goes in chunk 1 again and so on
      if(i % 2 === 0){
        chunk2.push(inputArray[i]);
      } else {
        chunk1.push(inputArray[i]);

      }

    }

    console.log('chunk1',chunk1);
    console.log('chunk2',chunk2);

  };
  
    chunkify(input);
```

Comment: Can you show code that you've tried? We can help you understand what is going wrong. Asking for code to be written is not the purpose of stackoverflow

Comment: its not clear which one is input which one is desired output? Will you please reedit the question

Comment: where did theme10 go?

Comment: @Supercool. theme 10 is in the first array, i

Comment: @Supercool. please check my edit

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  please check my edit

Comment: @CertainPerformance  please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```js
const input = [{
    name: "Theme 1"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 2"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 3"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 4"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 5"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 6"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 7"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 8"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 9"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 10"
  }
];

function chunk(input,size){
    let out = Array(size).fill([])
    let ptr = 0
    input.forEach(e=>{
        out[ptr] = [... out[ptr],e]
        ptr+=1;
        if(ptr==size)ptr=0
    })
    return out
}

console.log(chunk(input,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `Skipper` constructor:

```js
const testArray = [{test:1}, {test:2}, {test:3}, {test:4}, {test:5}, {test:6}, {test:7}];
function Skipper(array){
  this.skip = (start, count = 2)=>{
    const a = [];
    for(let i=start,l=array.length; i<l; i+=count){
      a.push(array[i]);
    }
    return a;
  }
}
const skipper = new Skipper(testArray);
console.log(skipper.skip(0)); console.log(skipper.skip(1));
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to chunk the arrays by creating sets e.g. the desired output i want is `[{test:1}, {test:3}, {test:5}, {test:7}]
[ {test:2},  {test:4},  {test:6}, ]`

Comment: So you really want an nth incrementer. Hold on.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```js
const input = [{
    name: "Theme 1"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 2"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 3"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 4"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 5"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 6"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 7"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 8"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 9"
  },
  {
    name: "Theme 10"
  }
];

const m = 3;
const output = input.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
  if (acc[i % m])
   acc[i % m].push(cur)
  else
   acc[i % m] = [cur];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/czuL354h/

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce()`

```js
const input = [{name: "Theme 1"},{name: "Theme 2"},{name: "Theme 3"},{name: "Theme 4"},{name: "Theme 5"},{name: "Theme 6" },{name: "Theme 7"},{name: "Theme 8"},{name: "Theme 9"},{ name: "Theme 10"}
];
const makeChunk = (arr,number) => {
    let index=0;
    return arr.reduce((acc,input) =>{
             if(!acc[index])acc.push([])
             acc[index].push(input);
             index=(index+1)%number;
             return acc;
    },[]);
}
console.log(makeChunk(input,3));
```